USD Import Context Error
I am trying to import a USDC file, I am using a custom built QT tool that has a UI, that I am using to manage my assets but each time I try to import something I get a context is incorrect issue.
Any help would be great!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Pipeline\studio_global\master\dev\tools\scene_manager\tabs\build\ui\build_tab.py", line 290, in <lambda>
    self.build_btn.clicked.connect(lambda status,: self.C_build_btn())
  File "F:\Pipeline\studio_global\master\dev\tools\scene_manager\tabs\build\ui\build_tab.py", line 423, in C_build_btn
    bpy.ops.wm.usd_import(filepath=usd_file_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 109, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.wm.usd_import.poll() failed, context is incorrect


Hello, without seeing the part of your script that calls this, it's hard to know exactly why this error pops up. Cheers

Hi, basically the function that is running this, only has the bpy.ops.wm.usd_import with a usd_file_path as argument to export to , just those 2 lines.
